# Is there a function to fill a bigger array with values from a smaller array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of say zeros
`a=[0,0,0,0,0]`
and an array
`b=[1,2,3]`
say the starting index is 0 then it fill array 'a' from starting index with values from 'b'
start_index=0

```
a=[1,2,3,0,0]
```

now b=[4,5]
start index=3 then it should add like this

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function, but you can use assigning to a slice to make your own:

```py
def fill_array(dest, src, start_index=0):
    dest[start_index:] = src

a = [0] * 5
fill_array(a, [1, 2, 3], 0)
fill_array(a, [4, 5], 3)
print(a) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, just forgo the function altogether:

```py
a = [0] * 5
a[0:] = [1, 2, 3]
a[3:] = [4, 5]
print(a) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```